# When re-saving a GeoJSON file to a shapefile, the .dbf significantly increases in size

Tags: qgis, shapefile, geojson, convert, dbf

When re-saving a GeoJSON file to a shapefile, the .dbf significantly increases in size to the point where the file size becomes unmanageable.

For example, I re-saved a 250 MB GeoJSON file to shapefile and the resulting .dbf file in the shapefile grew to 2 GB.

Why is this?

I'm using QGIS 3.6.3.

Comment: More details are necessary. How was the original dBase file defined? How was the second defined? How many row in each? Please [Edit] the question.

Comment: @Vince what do you mean by defined? My process was to re-save an existing geojson file as a shapefile using QGIS. Where would I find out how the dBase was defined? There are about 86,000 rows and 100 columns.

Comment: To "re-save" something implies that it was in that format originally.  dBase uses fixed-width columns so if the table was re-created with the same number of columns of the same width, with the same number of rows, it should be the same size. It is not possible to compare ASCII GeoJSON and binary dBase storage sizes in any meaningful way.